# String Cleaning Function Producing Unexpected Output

Tags: data-cleaning

I am looking to clean the profile column of the following dataframe:

```
name    profile
6   Pedro   ["\n Design ...
7   Leonardo    ["\n Design ...
8   Daniel  ["\n JavaScript ...
9   Mario   ["\n JavaScript ...
10  Christi     ["\n Design ...
```

I've tested the following function on individual rows...

```
def clean_profile(row):
    for index, row in new_df2["profile"].items():
        str_row = str(row)
        clean_row = (
            '""'.join(str_row)
            .replace(",", "")
            .replace('""', "")
            .replace("\\n                    ", "")
            .replace("                ", "")
        )
    return clean_row
```

...and found it to transform this str:

```
'["\\n                    Design                ","\\n                    Design                "]'
```

to this cleaned string:

```
'["Design","Design"]'
```

(the extra replace methods are necessary to clean really messy strings like this one:)

```
'{"Tools ""    Google Analytics            ":null,"    Google Adsense            ":null,"    MailChimp            ":null,"    Google Adwords            ","Containers ""    Docker            ","Digital ""    SEO            ":null,"    Email Marketing            ":null,"    Article Writing            ":null,"    Market Research            ":null,"    Social Media            ":null,"    Inbound Marketing            ","*Nix ""    Ubuntu            ":null,"    Linux            ","Java ""    Java    ","Python ""    Django            ":null,"    Python    ":null,"    Flask            ","Databases ""    MySQL Management            ":null,"    MongoDB Management            ":null,"    PostgreSQL Management            ","Visual ""    Brand Design            ":null,"    Graphic Design            ":null,"    Logo Design            ","HTML ""    HTML    ","Version Control ""    Git            ","PHP ""    Laravel            ":null,"    Wordpress            ":null,"    PHP    ":null,"    Symfony            ","Mobile ""    React Native            ","Ruby ""    Ruby    ":null,"    Sinatra            ":null,"    Rails            ","Project Management ""    Agile Methodology            ":null,"    Client Management            ":null,"    Scrum            ","English ""    Written English    ":null,"    Spoken English            ","Configuration Management ""    Chef            ","Webserver ""    Nginx            ":null,"    Apache            ","CDN ""    AWS CloudFront            ":null,"    Cloudflare            ","Other ""    C++            ","Experience ""    Creative Direction            ":null,"    UI/UX Design            ":null,"    Wireframing            ","JavaScript ""    JavaScript    ":null,"    TypeScript            ":null,"    Redux            ":null,"    Angular JS            ":null,"    Angular            ":null,"    D3.js            ":null,"    Node.js            ":null,"    React            ":null,"    Flux            ":null,"    Express            ","CSS ""    SASS            ":null,"    LESS            ":null,"    CSS    ","Hosting ""    Heroku            ":null,"    Digital Ocean            ":null,"    AWS            ","Automated Testing ""    TDD            ":null,"    Automated Testing    ":null,"    BDD            ":null,"    Jest            ","Traditional ""    Outbound Marketing            ":null,"    Brand Strategy            ","Data Science ""    Data Science    ":null,"    Data Analysis            ":null,"    Machine Learning            ":null,"    Data Visualization            ":null,"    R            ":null,"    Statistics            "}'
```

When I loop through the all rows of the dataframe, I get either this repeated for all rows:

```
["JavaScriptDevOpsPHPJavaScriptDevOpsPHP"]
```

or this:

```
<function clean_profile at 0x0845CB20>
```

I've tried a few different things and nothing has worked...is anyone able to explain what's going on here and maybe suggest a better way of cleaning these strings?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you didn't declare an initial clean_row variable outside of the for loop, so your clean_row will always equal whatever string you cleaned last.

```
def clean_profile(row):
    clean_row = "" //added this line
    for index, row in new_df2["profile"].items():
        str_row = str(row)
        clean_row = (
            '""'.join(str_row)
            .replace(",", "")
            .replace('""', "")
            .replace("\\n                    ", "")
            .replace("                ", "")
        )
    return clean_row
```

Additionally, I'd look into the strip function for your string cleaning. Here is a good example: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/clean-the-string-data-in-the-given-pandas-dataframe/

Comment: Thank you Joseph! I've been trying to integrate more functions into my code, so your insight is really helpful:) Thanks again!